# how can I make shortcut the menu, Language -> J -> Javascript

Tags: notepad++

I often open  .aspx  file.

I used to do   language -> j -> javascript. every time when I open aspx file

it's really annoying

I like to make short cut or macro.

But I cannot find this menu  on Shortcut mapper.

How Can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can associate the *aspx* extension with Javascript like this:

- go to *Settings/Style Configurator...*
- select Javascript language
- enter *aspx* in *User ext.* textbox
- click *Save & Close*

I hope this solves your problem

Comment: @rslite what do you suggest for shell scricpt files with no extension?

Answer (score 2):

For the case where the extension does not match the language you wish to select or there is no extension, you could use a macro program such as AutoHokey to automate the menu selection.

For example, using windows+v as the shortcut:

This code sends alt+L, then presses J, then presses the down arrow, then finally hits enter. You may need to use the "SetKeyDelay" command depending on the speed of your system and the responsiveness of your Notepad++.

```
#v::
Send, {AltDown}L{AltUp}J{Down}{Enter}
return
```

Or, another example, for VBA

```
#v::
Send, {AltDown}L{AltUp}V{Enter}
return
```

Comment: Why are you posting this on a *7 year old question* when the accepted solution not only works fine but is arguably preferable?

Comment: Simply an alternative solution. Works in a case where the file is not labeled as the extension language you wish to select. Are you suggesting I should not post alternative solutions?

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting that. But a (and I mean no offence) low-rep user posting an answer to an almost decade old question is a red-flag. If I were you I'd edit your answer (and any other similar answers you may write) to explain what value they add over/in addition to the existing answers. I end up flagging a lot of these that I see in the queue because of low-quality/plagarism (which is not the case here).

Comment: Thanks, I edited it a little bit to include the use case.

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard shortcut for language settings is Alt+L. Then choose your language. I find this simpler than navigating the same via Mouse.

Comment: If you want to improve another answer, please leave a comment to it.

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread first while seeking the answer I eventually found and I wish to share it here. All credit to [this post on the Notepad++ forums](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/18988/how-to-change-syntax-via-hotkey/5?lang=en-US). I'm just reiterating it here.

You can create a macro to switch to a specific language and then set a keyboard shortcut via the built-in menu: `Macro > Modify Shortcut/Delete Macro`. Unfortunately you cannot **record** this macro, but you can manually edit the file macros are saved to.

The standard location for this file is `%AppData%\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml`. In this XML file there is a section called `<Macros>` that should look something like this (this one macro came predefined to my install):

```
<Macros>
    <Macro name="Trim Trailing Space and Save" Ctrl="yes" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="83">
        <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="42024" lParam="0" sParam="" />
        <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="41006" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    </Macro>
</Macros>
```

To add an entry to switch to JavaScript, add these lines:

```
<Macro name="Switch Language to JS" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">
    <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="46007" lParam="0" sParam="" />
</Macro>
```

The key part here is the `wParam="46007"` this is the menu item ID that refers to the JavaScript language menu item. To add other languages check the source file [here](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/blob/master/PowerEditor/src/menuCmdID.h#L439) for a list of menu IDs. Note how lines are defined like so:

```
#define    IDM_LANG_HTML               (IDM_LANG + 5)
#define    IDM_LANG_XML                (IDM_LANG + 6)
#define    IDM_LANG_JS                 (IDM_LANG + 7)
```

`IDM_LANG` is equal to 46000, so `IDM_LANG_JS` (JavaScript) is equal to 46000+7, hence `wParam="46007"`.

After adding these lines, you should have an overall section like so:

```
<Macros>
    <Macro name="Trim Trailing Space and Save" Ctrl="yes" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="83">
        <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="42024" lParam="0" sParam="" />
        <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="41006" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    </Macro>
    <Macro name="Switch Language to JS" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">
        <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="46007" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    </Macro>
</Macros>
```

Notepad++ doesn't read this file on the fly, so you'll need to relaunch after making changes. And an important thing to note, if you try to edit this file **with** Notepad++ it will overwrite your changes when you close the application (it saves the running application settings on exit). The easiest solution is to use a different text editor to edit the file. Or you can open, edit, save the file, set to read-only, close and reopen Notepad++, clear read-only.

Comment: You can actually edit the `shortcuts.xml` file with Notepad++ just fine. The only case where your changes will be ignored and overwritten is, if in the same session where you are editing the file, you also modify macros/shortcuts using Notepad++'s UI. To make sure that this does not happen, just restart Notepad++, edit the file and save without doing anything else in Notepad++, and then restart Notepad++ again.

Comment: I wanted to change to a user-defined language in a macro. Naturally, the menu item ID for that is not present in Notepad++ source code. But I saw the ID numbers `IDM_LANG_USER` (46180) and `IDM_LANG_USER_LIMIT` (46210). Presumably, user-defined languages get IDs between those two. Indeed, I was able to change to the user-defined language I wanted using the ID 46181.